# React with Webpacker is failing to load

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails, bundler, yarnpkg

Now that I have resolved my issue with Ruby, the React part with webpacker is failing to load probably as below.

```
yarn install v1.21.1 
[1/4] Resolving packages... 
[2/4] Fetching packages... 
info fsevents@1.2.11: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module. 
info "fsevents@1.2.11" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation. 
[3/4] Linking dependencies... 
warning " > @babel/preset-react@7.8.3" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0". 
warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-display-name@7.8.3" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0". 
warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx@7.8.3" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0". 
warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-self@7.8.3" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0". 
warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-source@7.8.3" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0". 
warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx > @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx@7.8.3" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0". 
warning " > webpack-dev-server@3.10.1" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0". 
warning "webpack-dev-server > webpack-dev-middleware@3.7.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0". 
[4/4] Building fresh packages... 
Done in 71.58s.
```

Comment: have you tried to uninstall nio4r, remove gemfile.lock before bundle install?

Comment: Try and keep your questions focused on the issue at hand. Referencing earlier problems just confuses the issue.

Comment: What does "failing to load" mean here? That looks like it installed.

Comment: My apologies - I just deleted the earlier stuff as resolved issue. I am unsure but I think this is an issue with Yarn.

Answer (score 0):

Since I found this question while looking for the same problem, I will post my findings here as well.

**Some background knowledge:**

It are peer dependencies that are required here. Peer dependencies are dependencies that are not being installed when you run yarn or npm install. If you what to know more about peer dependencies and how the NPM package system work, read [this article](https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2016/08/24/understanding-the-npm-dependency-model/).

Node is using semantic versioning and this is explained [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies).

**Now to this specific problem:**

After reading the following issues on github:

- [Unmet babel core peer dependency](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/733)
- [unmet peer dependency warnings using yarn](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1190)
- [babel-core@^7.0.0-0 should be babel-core@^7.0.0-bridge.0](https://github.com/babel/babel-bridge/issues/5)

For me, I came to the conclusion I can ignore them since it seems to be a yarn bug not finding the correct package I have installed on my system. Never the less in case, I get problems at some point I need to do a closer deep dive into this. If this happens I will update the answer in the future.